# Como criar rotas privadas com nextJs

Tags: react, next.js

Olá, gostaria de um auxilio para a criação de rotas privadas usando NextJs. Todos os arquivos depositados dentro do diretório *pages* se tornam rotas acessiveis, em minha aplicação algumas destas devem ser acessiveissomente quando o usuário estiver logado.
Atualmente estou usando useEffect para verificar se existe um objeto chamado *username* no *sessionStorage*, o código abaixo está na página de login e redireciona o usuário caso ele já esteja conectado:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const session = sessionStorage.getItem('username');
  if (session) {
    router.push(router.query.followPage || '/');
  }
}, [router]);
```

Esse método está longe de ser eficiente, e redireciona o usuário após o load inicial da página mostrando ao usuário componentes da tela, alem de ser mais lento no redirecionamento. Validações semelhantes há em outras páginas, nestas se *username* não existe o usuário é direcionado a página de login.

Encontrei algumas instruções para criar um HOC (Higher-Order Component) e envolver minhas páginas privadas com ele, isso parece promissor mas não consegui compreender como o autor propõe que os dados do usuário sejam validados, isso é, como a sessão do usuário é verificada pela função criada por ele *checkUserAuthentication* nesta fonte: https://medium.com/@eslamifard.ali/how-to-simply-create-a-private-route-in-next-js-38cab204a99c

Usar a função *getInitialProps* do next para verificar a autenticação do usuário no lado do servidor e redireciona-lo a partir dai parece eficiente, encontrei algumas fontes sugerindo passar um token no header da requisição mas de novo, não compreendi como isso funciona caso o usuário acesse a página diretamente pela url sem usar algum link interno da página.

Então qual é a melhor forma de criar rotas privadas com o NextJs?

Comment: A aplicação atual que estou desenvolvendo é muito simples e não precisa de grandes níveis de segurança, uma simples validação sobre a sessão do usuário já é o suficiente para o meu caso, uma resposta que use uma validação com base no *sessionStorage* já será bem vinda, mas caso queira contribuir com uma resposta mais avançada para usuários futuros que busquem por isso, fique a vontade.

Comment: Apenas um questionamento a se fazer... Nesse cenário (em que o usuário tem que estar logado para visualizar a página) será que realmente vale a pena utilizar Next? O principal propósito do Next é permitir SSR (e similares) para melhorar o SEO. Mas se a página é privada, isso não é necessário. Enfim, não estou falando para deixar de usar Next, mas é algo para se pensar. Autenticação com Next não é muito trivial de se fazer porque tem que sincronizar o _token_ de autorização entre cliente e servidor, o que pode dar um trabalhozinho.

Comment: É um ótimo questionamento, eu não deixei claro na pergunta mas estou estendendo um aplicação já existente, tratasse de um site que foi construído em next e que agora o cliente quer incluir duas páginas das quais somente ele tenha acesso, não há nenhuma informação realmente privada nelas, mas o cliente não quer expor as mesmas por enquanto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A resposta estava na minha frente o tempo todo, *sessionStorage* e *localStorage* não podem ser acessados nas funções executadas no servidor, mas os cookies podem, então a solução se você quer criar uma rota privada como uma autenticação simples é salvar sua sessão nos cookies.
Eu usei a lib *js-cookies* para manipular os cookies da minha aplicação mas isso é opcional. O exemplo abaixo demonstra como gravar o cookie no sistema:

```js
import cookie from 'js-cookie';

function signIn(email, password) {
  // aqui é sua validação no servidor
  cookie.set('nomeDoCookie', 'valorDoCookie', { expires: 1, path: '/' });
  // você pode incluir um redirecionamento aqui se quiser
}
```

Agora na página que você deseja tornar privada, exporte a função *getServerSideProps* como demonstrado abaixo:

```js
export async function getServerSideProps(ctx) {
  const isAuthenticated = (req) => {
    if (!req?.headers?.cookie) {
      return undefined;
    }

    const match = req.headers.cookie
      .split(';')
      .find((item) => item.trim().startsWith('nomeDoCookie='));

    if (!match) {
      return undefined;
    }

    return match.split('=')[1];
  };

  if (!isAuthenticated(ctx.req)) {
    ctx.res.writeHead(303, { Location: 'paginaDeLogin' });
    ctx.res.end();
  }

  return { props: {} };
}
```

É claro que você deve criar a função *isAuthenticated* em um arquivo separado e apenas chama-lo onde precisar. Essa é uma forma simples de fazer uma rota privada usando cookies, você também pode usar a função *getInitialProps* para validar os cookies, mas não é aconselhável pois torna o código mais complexo já que é necessário fazer validações para saber se a execução esta acontecendo no servidor ou no cliente

> getServerSideProps is very similar to getInitialProps, meaning that it gets called every time that you load the page, but the code is only executed on the server.

Fonte: https://www.datocms.com/blog/how-the-new-next-js-9-3-preview-mode-works

É importante destacar que neste exemplo estou apenas verificando se o cookie existe, não estou verificando se ele é válido ou não, no meu caso isso é o suficiente, mas talvez você queira verificar alguns exemplos mais seguros de verificação, busque por *auth* na página de exemplos do nextJs para descobrir algumas formas de autenticação. https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples

Esse artigo foi útil para mim enquanto estava pesquisando formas de fazer o que eu precisava: https://medium.com/@positivecarlos/authentication-on-universal-react-with-next-js-b441ef458046